# Excel VBA To Allow Manual Input if List Value Selected

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have validation cells that are of type XLValidationList. Is it possible in vba to allow manual input into that cell if a specific value in the drop down menu is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning False to .ShowAlert property of the validation object seemed to do the trick